# Gedit's slow when there're unsaved changes

Tags: lubuntu, gedit

**THE PROBLEM:** I'm finding that gedit is working incredibly slow when there are unsaved changes. The mouse-pointer flickers and typing is painfully slow.

**PARTIAL FIXES:** As soon as I save the changes I've made to the file, it immediately speeds up again until I make some more changes. Also, I discovered that running gedit as root completely fixes the problem -- it never slows down, whether there are unsaved changes or not.

**ALREADY TRIED:** I've disabled all gedit plugins, and the problem persists.

I am extremely reluctant to work with `gedit` in `sudo`. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here? I've searched around for a while, but haven't found anyone with the same issue...

Comment: How is leafpad?

Comment: Leafpad runs perfectly, but doesn't have syntax highlighting or color themes :-/

Comment: I think that could be slowing it down really. Shame... Strange that it's only when there are saves. Why are you avoiding running gedit as root?

Comment: My laptop can handle pretty intense IDEs such as eclipse, so I'd be surprised if Gedit's requirements were the cause (especially since gedit runs perfectly smoothly as root).
I'd prefer not to run as root because of the security problems. It's not really an ideal fix to have a terminal open with root access.

Comment: I am experiencing the exact same problem, besides the pc heats up and the cooling fan goes crazy. I am using Lubuntu 15.04. Might it be related to some conflicts with multiple keyboard layouts? As far as I can remember the problem arose after I replaced fcitx with iBus for Chinese input.

Please share your knowledge if you solve this issue!

Comment: I am having a similar issue on a Xubuntu18.04 machine. Opening a 5 page bash script on a mounted samba share takes in mousepad <1sec, in gedit 39sec. Obviously its difficult to analyse the issue without detailed system info, but it would be already helpful to get the hints toward a strategy on how to nail down the issue (like what to liook for in which log or what test to make).